# page content not rendering properly - python / django?

Tags: python, jinja2

I am running ubuntu 16.4 with apache2 webserver

I am trying to setup this site, downloaded from github: https://github.com/mozilla/http-observatory-website

Unfortunately, there is no instructions to follow :(

if put these files in the working/public directory and point to index.html from the browser i.e. http://localhost/laravel/work/public/

The page comes up but what seems to be djamgp code shows up.. there is also two python files and a Makefile in the same directory but not sure what to do with those or if anything needs to be compiled - which i also dont have a clue how to do.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like: https://snag.gy/4npmjY.jpg

[image]

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: why did you assume it was laravel?

Comment: i appear to be incorrect.. after some google search it appears to be something related to Python / Django - no idea how to render these pages

Comment: to render them you need a template engine ... e.g `Blade` which laravel uses ...

Comment: from what i see it's a python app ...  render.py should render it

Comment: i think i need python-django framework.. installing now per https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: it's not Django. It's Jinja2. That is actually a templating engine.

Comment: so do i need jinja2 engine or something to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source, you'd need the [Jinja templating engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). The easiest way to install it is by running `pip install jinja2`.

That said, I do recommend that you follow the virtualenv instructions on the DigitalOcean tutorial posted as a comment. It is going to be much cleaner and easier to maintain.

The idea behind the virtual environment is to install inside of it, instead of your system-wide python installation all the dependencies that you can possibly need.

Answer (score 0):

cloning the package this way solved the problem and gave me the right files to add to /var/www

git clone -b gh-pages https://github.com/mozilla/http-observatory-website.git